# Where do I find my public key in Metamask?

Tags: metamask

The official guides suggest this, but it's the address. Where should I be looking? [image]

Comment: Metamask only shows you the address and the private key. You could derive the public key from the private key following steps like: https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/how-to-create-an-ethereum-wallet-address-from-a-private-key-ae72b0eee27b/

Comment: Is this something new?

Comment: I'm not sure. Anyways, your private key in Metamask is used as the Master Private Key to create multiple public keys and addresses. If you switch accounts and request to see the private key in each one, you will see that they share the same private key.